# How to pass rows in MPI_Allgather in Fortran using MPI_TYPE_VECTOR

Tags: fortran, row, mpi

I have a fortran array in which each row is calculated by a process.  I then want to gather the full array on all processes. I can get it work for two variations of mpi_allgather, but not the more elegant one using mpi_type_vector given here, for example:

```
   program allGather
      ! test of MPI_allgather with rows
      use mpi
      implicit none
      integer i, mpierr, myRank, noProc
      integer, allocatable:: survived(:,:)
      integer rowtype
      real(4) ran

      call MPI_INIT( mpierr )
      call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myRank, mpierr) ! get rank of this process in world      
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, noProc, mpiErr)

      allocate( survived(noProc,2) ) ! used to find best solution out of all processes

      ! Each process calculates one row of survived and each row is tagged with it's rank for sorting
      ! For this test example, just use a random number
      call RANDOM_SEED()
      call RANDOM_NUMBER(ran)
      survived(myRank+1,:) = [int(1.e6*ran), myRank]
      write(*,'(3(a,i0),a)') 'Rank: ', myRank, ' survived = [', survived(myRank+1,1), ', ', survived(myRank+1,2),']'
      call mpi_barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpiErr)      

      ! specify type to capture rows of survived
      call MPI_TYPE_VECTOR(2, 1, noProc, MPI_INTEGER, rowtype, mpierr)
      call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(rowtype, mpierr)
      call MPI_allgather(MPI_IN_PLACE, 1, rowtype, survived     , 1, rowtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpierr)

      if (myRank == 0) then
         write(*,'(/,a)') 'Passed array is:'
         write(*,'(i0,'', '',i0)') (survived(i,:),i=1,noProc)
      end if

      deallocate( survived ) ! used to find best solution out of all processes
      call MPI_FINALIZE(mpierr)          
   end program allGather
```

This generates an output on 4 processes something like:

```
Rank: 0 survived = [819935, 0]
Rank: 1 survived = [971609, 1]
Rank: 2 survived = [859684, 2]
Rank: 3 survived = [747759, 3]

Passed array is:
819935, 0
0, 1
0, 0
0, 0
```

Clearly I'm missing something.  Can someone point out my error? Thanks!

Comment: you need to resize your derived datatype so its extent is the size of an `INTEGER`. If you are still struggling, please edit your question with a [MCVE].

Comment: I agree with GIlles above.  I am upvoting your question because resizing a datatype's extent is a problem that trips up many people (Like me!) when they start using MPI derived types.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Gilles by size of an INTEGER, so I've provided an example.